# Export style in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Wondering whether Cognito Forms has an option of exporting forms into a specifically formatted Excel document.

I work at a construction company, and we use our forms in house, for employees to fill out required safety information about each job site. When they fill out the information, I would like it to export into a backend form to keep for our records. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can print individual entries using the Print button and save to PDF (with Google Chrome) or print to PDF if you have Acrobat or another product that enables PDF printing.  Also, we are planning to support [PDF/DOCX Export](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy) in a future release.  We have not yet considered XLSX export of individual entries.  We also support restful JSON webhooks for posting submitted entry data into other systems, which is a great way to track things without relying on physical documents.